# What does ActiveSync on Android(Nexus One) actually do?

Tags: android, exchange, activesync, outlook-web-access

Under the accounts settings of my nexus one I added a Microsoft ActiveSync account and pointed it to our OWA url.  It doesn't seem to do anything, and I'm not really sure what it is supposed to do.  I have both email sync and contacts sync enabled in the settings, but none of the email I get through outlook shows up on the phone nor are there any contacts added to my contacts list.

When I setup the account settings if I type something in wrong it gives me an error, so it is doing something to test the connection, so to some extent I must have it setup right.  It just doesn't seem to do anything.

What is it actually supposed to do?  Where would the contacts and emails show up if it sync'd successfully?  How can I test it to ensure I have the correct URL specified?

Answer (score 1):

Can you successfully browse from the phone to the OWA URL? I don't have an Android phone, but I'm assuming there is an option for using SSL with the Activesync connection, have you tried that both on and off?